# PHP Regular expression is validating, but the javascript is not

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am trying to write some reg expression validation on a PHP form, and I have the following:

```
/^([+]{1}[0-9]{1,2}[\s]?[0-9]{1,10}[\s][0-9]{1-6}?)|([+][0-9]{1,2}[\s]?[0-9]{1,4}[\s]?[0-9]{1,6})|([+]?[0-9]{2,3}?[\s]?[0-9]{1,3}[\s])?([0-9]{1,5})?[0-9]{3}[\s]?[0-9]{5,6}$/i
```

but the javascript version shown below is claiming it not to be valid, even though I can successfully submit the form showing that the PHP version will accept the expression.

```
/^([+][0-9]{1,2}[\\s]?[0-9]{1,10}[\\s][0-9]{1-6}?)|([+][0-9]{1,2}[\\s]?[0-9]{1,4}[\\s]?[0-9]{1,6})|([+]?[0-9]{2,3}?[\\s]?[0-9]{1,3}[\\s])?([0-9]{1,5})?[0-9]{3}[\\s]?[0-9]{5,6}$/i
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you post the javascript code where the regex is used?

Comment: You should probably add some examples of strings that should pass and strings that should fail.

Comment: Is `[+]` working? I thought that + is a reserved keyword. Shouln't it be masked to `[\+]`?

Comment: @Fuzzyma - Everything inside `[]` is escaped automatically (except `]`)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 `-` won't work: `[a-z]`. Also `^` wont work: [^\s]. And of course the backslash won't work

Comment: `{1-6}` That's probably not what you want (towards the end of the first capture grouping).

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be for international phone numbers, would it?

Comment: it is meant for phone numbers, primarily UK, so +44 1227 000000, +441227 000000, 00000 000000, 00000000000, 0044 1227 000000 should all work.

As I said it does validate if I submit the form in php, however as I am writing into the fields the javascipt throws an error showing the user its not valid.

Comment: Honestly, you're better off removing the spaces and then validating the result. The space is really just there for visual representation and is not part of the actual number (when you dial, you don't hit a button for the space).

Comment: @MaxMeijer - Yea.. except `-^` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to escape `\` by `\\`, which is **not** needed

And you should escape `+` by `\+` if you are trying to match the literal `+`

Comment: While this is true (at least the first part of what you said), it is far from the only problem.